# Multiple SSL setup issue migrating to Jetty 9.4.25

Tags: java, jetty

I am upgrading to Jetty 9.4.25, however when I start Jetty it gave me error

KeyStores with multiple certificates are not supported on the base class org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.

Below is part of my jetty.xml, is there a way to modify the xml to allow multiple keystores? Thanks in advance!

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
<New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStorePath">${keystore.Path}</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword"
            deprecated="jetty.keystore.password" default="xxx" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="KeyStoreType">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.keyStoreType" default="xxx" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="KeyStoreProvider">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.keyStoreProvider" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.keyManagerPassword"
            deprecated="jetty.keymanager.password" default="xxx" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePath">${keystore.Path}</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.trustStorePassword"
            deprecated="jetty.truststore.password" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="TrustStoreType">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.trustStoreType" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="TrustStoreProvider">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.trustStoreProvider" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="EndpointIdentificationAlgorithm"></Set>
    <Set name="NeedClientAuth">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.needClientAuth" deprecated="jetty.ssl.needClientAuth"
            default="xxx" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="WantClientAuth">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.wantClientAuth" deprecated="jetty.ssl.wantClientAuth"
            default="xxx" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="useCipherSuitesOrder">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.useCipherSuitesOrder"
            default="xxx" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="sslSessionCacheSize">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.sslSessionCacheSize"
            default="xxx" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="sslSessionTimeout">
        <Property name="jetty.sslContext.sslSessionTimeout" default="xxx" />
    </Set>
</New>
```

Comment: Jetty 9.4.25 does not contain that block of XML in it's `jetty.xml`.   Why are you customizing it (against the advice that Jetty specifically prints out when you start)?

Comment: Multiple Keystores (what you ask for in your question) and multiple certificates (what the error is saying) are different things.  Which one are you trying to address?